# If statement looks to not extend to other templates

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a problem with one of my if statements on my django template.

Currently I have this on my base.html which extends to other templates:

base.html

```
{% if user.is_superuser %}
    <h2>Admin Menu</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
        {% if approved %}
            <td><a href="{% url rates-disable_rates %}" class="mbbutton ui-state-active ui-corner-all">Disable Rates</a></td>
        {% else %}
            <td><a href="{% url rates-approve_rates %}" class="mbbutton ui-state-active ui-corner-all">Approve Rates</a></td>
        {% endif %}
        </tr>
        {% if life %}
        {% include 'rates/admin_life_rates_menu.html' %}
        {% else %}
        {% include 'rates/admin_broker_rates_menu.html' %}
        {% endif %}
    </table>
{% endif %}
```

Now I have rates for certain categories, for example X rates, Y rates, etc.  Each with their own button.

Example:

```
<form method="get" action=".">
   <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="{{ product_code }}"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="paymode_code" value="{{ paymode_code }}"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="compoundmode_code" value="{{ compoundmode_code }}"/>
   {% if life %}<input type="hidden" name="life" value="{{ life }}"/>{% endif %}
   {% if tfsa %}<input type="hidden" name="tfsa" value="{{ tfsa }}"/>{% endif %}
</form>
```

If rates are approved the link is displayed as 'disable rates' (the reverse, naturally) and vice versa is the rates havent been approved.

So my issue is that the if statement doesn't seem to work when I click to view the other rates.

If the rates are already approved, the link shows approve, even though that is incorrect.  Any ideas as to why this if statement wouldn't be working?

Thanks so much and if there is any more code segments I need to display just ask, and I will gladly put them up.

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: And I presume that you are actually setting the context variable `approved` appropriately in your view?

Comment: I am using version 1.2.1

Comment: @Chris that was it.  I passed the approved through the regular view context but not through my admin view context.  Needed another "set of eyes".  If you put that as an answer I will accept it.  Thanks so much

Comment: If you can reasonably, upgrade to 1.3. It's just better. One thing which is better is the `include` template tag and the ability to specify variables to be defined in the sub-context. (Not that it is directly related to this question, but some related things could become easier.)

Comment: Yeah more than likely we will be making the switch soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're not providing the `approved` variable in your view, so it evaluates to `''`, which is false.